# How to build game cross-platform in window 8, window phone 8, android using html5?

Tags: android, window, windows-phone-8, game-engine

Is there any way to build game cross-platform in window 8, window phone 8, android using html5?

Can I convert game written by HTML5/Javascript on window 8 to window phone 8, to android?

I search for game framework libgdx (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) is available on Android, can I use it for HTML5 game on window 8?

Comment: HTML5 is supported by all smart phones. You have to check the version of OS which you want to support like Android started supporting HTML5 from 2.1. Like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Phonegap**](http://phonegap.com/).

It allows you to create you cross platform applications. PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.

There are other tools also like [**Titanium**](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/), [**Snecha**](http://www.sencha.com/) that allows you to create cross platform applications.

Comment: Yes, Titanium is my choice http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch is there... this is cross platform...

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.Download the **[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/download/)**.

please follow the this **[link](https://build.phonegap.com/)** to know more .